# Delete a Google Place

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am trying to delete a place that I have added earlier using Places Add. (Refer https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/add-place). However, I get a response Invalid Request. I am using the place_id returned from the Places search for deleting this place. I was able to delete some of the other places, however  specific place is no getting deleted. Any reasons for this? How can I get this deleted?

I also would like to know if there is an option to Edit a place. What if some of my details have changed and I need to update this?

Comment: does that mean your place successfully passed through the Google Maps moderation process..? you can see if you can get info using the same place id using other apps.

Comment: @kaho yes, I can see my place showing up in Google search results. I want to remove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you can not delete it, at least for now.

According to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/add-place#delete-place), if you can not delete your place, it probably means your place information has passed through the Google Maps moderation process, and made into the Google Places database. In this case, you have to go to maps.google.com, search your place and delete it as it is [mentioned in this q&a](https://support.google.com/mapmaker/answer/7195127?visit_id=637582097127060947-2786172152&hl=en&rd=1). However, due to the [Android urinating on the Apple logo](https://www.engadget.com/2015-04-24-google-maps-android-apple-piss.html) instant, editing will be [closed temporarily from May 12th](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/map-maker/news-and-announcements/crFEbGXJ-HI).

Comment: Map Maker reopening in early August: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/map-maker/fY-Cu6355pM